# (Solved) Sql Server Failover Clustering Error

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I want to install always on on Sql server 2019. I have two windows server 2016. I will not use active directory. I do the installation as described on the site where I will leave the link below. When I add node2 to the failover cluster while installing, I get the "**you do not have administrative privileges on the server node2**" error. How can I resolve this error? Thanks.

Guide site: https://www.emreozanmemis.com/windows-server-failover-cluster-uzerine-ms-sql-alwayson-kurulumu/

--Solved--

I solved the problem by running the following command on Powershell.

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Value 1

--Solved--

Comment: Does your Windows Admin user have the same Username and Password on both servers?

Comment: Yes it is same on both servers.

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168114/adding-cluster-admin-rights-in-windows-server-2012

Comment: The right way to post a solution is to create an _answer_, which you can mark as accepted and others can upvote if they find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue, and the solution was to add the same domain admin user to the local Administrator group in each node.